# Streaming results of a large db query in FastAPI takes too long

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, fastapi, aws-fargate

We have a tiny FastAPI deployed in Fargate Cluster, and the task is set to use 16vCPU's and 32GB Ram.

It queries data from Aurora, on a single table which has millions of records.

This is the code:

```py
@trade_router.get('/trades')
def read_item(symbol: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    with db as session:
        trades = session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM trades WHERE symbol = :symbol"), {"symbol": symbol.upper()})

    def iter_trades():
        for trade in trades:
            # send as csv
            yield f"{trade.trade_date}, {trade.symbol}, {trade.price}, {trade.quantity}\n"

    return StreamingResponse(iter_trades(), media_type="application/json")
```

Whilst the response is almost instant, some queries have to return 700k records, which can take upto 2 mins for all data to be returned.

If I run the same query directly to the database it only takes about 7 seconds to return 700k.

Maybe Python and FastAPI are just not the right solution. But is there anyway to increase the speed?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72577231/1028679) to a similar question says "You should not make a 700k row database request from FastAPI or any other web server."

Ok, so then how do I have the database do the work and return the entire result set? Do I need a materialized view, or should I partition the table for each symbol (as that is the only query param)?

**UPDATE**

It is a desktop client (C# .Net). We see no difference in performance whether the .Net code calls the endpoint, or the browser, or Postman or curl. Streaming the full 700k takes around 2mins in every case.

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206076/17865804). I would also suggest having a look at `websockets` - see related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74639030/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804)

Comment: @Chris Thanks. It is a desktop client (C# .Net). We see no difference in performance whether the .Net code calls the endpoint, or the browser, or Postman or curl. Streaming the full 700k takes around 2mins in every case.

Comment: What is the UI doing with 700k records at once? I'm guessing not displaying them in raw format unless you have a _really_ huge screen...? Is there any calculation you could do on the database side to not have to return them all in raw format to the client?

Comment: The data is simply a timestamp, a stock symbol and a price. The client is plotting them on a chart. No calculations involved anywhere in the pipeline.

Comment: Have you tried a python a client using `requests` or `httpx` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) (without, necessarily, printing the response out on client side), in order to find out where exactly the delay occurs (it might also have to do with plotting the data on a chart on client side). Regardless, iterating through 700k records and returning them might not be the best option. See if you can group the results (maybe by timestamp?) beforehand.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73754985/17865804) might be an alternative way

Comment: Can you time `session.execute(...)` to confirm that this is as fast as your direct query to the database?